# Can I publish a WordPress site as MIT?

Tags: licensing, gpl, mit, gpl-2, gnu

I know that WordPress is licensed GPLv2 (or later).

I also know that all things that use WordPress must also be GPLv2 (or later) compatible (eg. Plugins and Themes)

I also read somewhere that cracking/nulling premium plugins/themes are legal since these also must use GPLv2 (or later) license. **Source: [Can I get sued for using nulled WordPress plugins?](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-get-sued-for-using-nulled-WordPress-plugins)**

I will use version control (Git) for my [WordPress site running Bedrock](https://github.com/roots/bedrock), I am planning to release it as a public repository with MIT License.

WordPress is GPLv2 license but why is a [WordPress boilerplate Bedrock is released MIT](https://github.com/roots/bedrock/blob/master/LICENSE.md)?

Does it mean that I can release a Bedrock WordPress website as MIT license while also using premium themes and plugins?

Comment: How would you distribute the whole site via git, since WordPress makes use of a database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are free to publish your own software under MIT, as long as it doesn't include any GPL-covered components.

Wordpress themes and plugins do not have to be GPL-licensed, the must merely have a GPL-*compatible* license. MIT is GPL-compatible.